# How to add custom Views filters (for example, date between X & Y, but specified by myself)

Tags: views

As per title. I am aware that there is a specific filter for date between X and Y, but if I wanted to programmatically develop it, what ways are there to do this?

EDIT : To be more specific, I am using Views 3 so that I can use apache solr views on Drupal 6.

Answer (score 1):

Date ranges in solr views still being worked on - see http://drupal.org/node/642430 for latest patch from July 11 2011

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://www.hashbangcode.com/blog/creating-custom-views-filters-exposed-form-element-drupal-6-561.html. Maybe this helps you.

Comment: Thanks Nonsenz, I will take a look. I should be more specific and say that I am using Views 3 (so that I can use apache solr views.